# Ptr<Node> a = CreateObject < Node > ();

Tags: c++, class, object

While i am going through different examples in NS-3 ( network simulator) i came across a definition like this. I coudn't figure out what exactly this syntax means.

```
Ptr<Node>  a = CreateObject < Node > ();
```

In some other cases they use similar syntax, but RHS is quite different.

HelperClass help;

```
Ptr< xxx > a = help.somethingrandom();
```

or they prefix `const` before `xxx`.

I guess this is a different way of creating objects in c++. But it is still confusing. Can anyone please elaborate whats happening ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you heard about a concept of [templates](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/460/templates)?

Comment: i am not aware of templates.

Comment: They initialize an object by function result.

Comment: Sorry. I coudn't follow you. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Learning c++ by reading the code of a very complex system is probably the worst way I can imagine. I suggest you [choose a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and go from there.

Comment: Thank you. I have some basic idea about c++.( until class and object definitions) So other question is from which topic do you suggest me to start?

Comment: If you have a handy book. And you feel you covered the preliminary material. Read about templates (from your book). To see how c++ programmers use those concepts to come up with interesting techniques, I suggest https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Ptr` is some smart pointer class. It seems `CreateObject` is template function, with implementation that simply boils down to this:

```
template<typename Obj>
Ptr<Obj> CreateObject() {
  return Ptr<Obj>(new Obj);
}
```

The idea is that the code is generic, it will work for any type. Using a function ensures no resources leak during multiple initializations, if a constructor happens to throw an exception.

The standard library has an equivalent `std::shared_ptr`/`std::unique_ptr` with matching `std::make_shared`/`std::make_unique` functions.

Comment: Thank you. I am not aware of both smart pointers and template functions. So how can i understand this then?

Comment: Hi, i have gone through some basics of template. But didn't come across anything similar to the one that you have mentioned in the answer. Can you please give me a reference ( preferably video link) for that?